# Reinstall OS on Nexus 7

Tags: nexus-7, rom, operating-system

I had unlocked my Nexus 7 and everything was great for months. I came home from work and it was stuck in a boot loop. I somehow managed to delete the OS while trying to fix it. I have access to the Team Win Recovery Project v2.2.1 but nothing else. What's the best way to reload the OS?

Answer (score 1):

[XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=1673) is the only place to go.

They have plenty of ROMs to choose from, including stock builds for your Nexus if you want timely updates from big G.

Comment: Also look here: [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/16575)

Answer (score 0):

You could also try downloading the factory image from [Google](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images). There are instructions with how to use it on that site too. This will completely wipe your device including your files.